# ServiceLoader to find implementations of an interface

Tags: java, serviceloader

I tried to use the Java [ServiceLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) to find all classes that implement a specific interface like so:

```
loader = ServiceLoader.load(Operation.class);
try {
    for (Operation o : loader) {
        operations.add(o);
    }
} catch (ServiceConfigurationError e) {
    LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "Uncaught exception", e);
}
```

Unfortunately, when I run Eclipse in debug mode the ServiceLoader doesn't find any classes. I feel like I'm missing a trivial point...

Comment: Do you have `META-INF/services/fqcn.Operation` configured?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`ServiceLoader` cannot do it.

In order to expose class as a service that can be discovered by `ServiceLoader` you need to put its name into provider configuration file, as described in [Creating Extensible Applications With the Java Platform](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/spi.html)
.

There are no built-in ways find all classes that implement a particular interface. Frameworks that can do something similar use their own classpath scanning solutions (and even with custom classpath scanning it's not easy because `.class` files only store information about interfaces implemented directly, not transitively).

Answer (score 26):

If the implementations are ones that you wrote yourself, you could use [AutoService](https://github.com/google/auto/tree/master/service) to make them available through the `ServiceLoader` interface, eg

```
@AutoService(Operation.class)
class Foo implements FooInterface {

}

@AutoService(Operation.class)
class Bar extends Foo {

}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this suggestion! 

I just couldn't get the provider file to work. Must have been putting it in the wrong place or with a typo or something, but this worked right out of the box with maven.

You can find the latest version in the maven repository at http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.auto.service/auto-service

Comment: My pleasure! If you have improvements, please edit the answer for viewers from the future (in the future)

Comment: This AutoService is brilliant!

Comment: And nobody is afraid that is a release candidate?

Comment: @paul I don't think it's a problem in this case. ServiceLoader is pretty straight forward to utilize directly (just need to stick to the naming scheme under META-INF). AutoService gives you an easy shortcut using an annotation - but it still does just that - create a single file with the correct naming scheme under META-INF.

Answer (score 3):

In order to scan your classpath at runtime for implementations of specific interface you would need to use different solution eg. [Reflections](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections)  (notice **s** on the end, this is not java's Reflection API)